# Switch between ringer and vibrate based on schedule?

Tags: iphone

Certain times of the week I would like the phone to be on vibrate and other times of the week I want it to be on ringer.  I would like to setup a schedule for these changes to happen automatically.  Can this be done?  If not natively is there an app that can do this?

Comment: It seems like such a simple feature that has been extremely feasible for at least ten years now at least.  I'm surprised that even today it requires jailbreak to get it working on the latest and greatest phone.

Comment: iOS 6 contains a [Do Not Disturb](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5463) feature, which obviously does not require jailbreak. It can switch between silent & ring based on a schedule, though not vibrate & ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Auto Silent](http://iphonepackers.info/AutoSilent.htm) on Cydia (jailbreak).